# In which tidyverse package is :=?

Tags: r, dplyr, package, dependencies, tidyverse

I’m writing an R package, where I’m using `dplyr::rename()`. For the new name, I’m passing the new name as a string, i.e,

```
#’ @importFrom dplyr rename
my_function <- function(df,newcol,oldcol){

…

df <- df |> rename(!!newcol := oldcol)

…
}
```

When I run the checks, I get a warning suggesting I should declare where `:=` is, which I cannot find.

Comment: `:=` is from rlang, i.e. use `@importFrom rlang :=`

Comment: Use  ?`:=` or  ??`:=` in the console to check the function documentation to find the source package.

Answer (score 1):

Even though @stefan 's comment is right, as a side note you could also use `rename_with` syntax, which is a bit less cumbersome to write:

```
oldcol = "Petal.Length"
newcol = "petal_length"
iris %>% rename_with(~newcol, oldcol)
```

Comment: I suggest you try this with any dataset. For me, I get `! Can't subset columns that don't exist. ✖ Column \`oldcol\` doesn't exist.` (replacing `newcol` and `oldcol` appropriately for the dataset I tested against).

Comment: In my understanding, the second argument of `rename_with` is `.fn=`, which is a _function_, not a symbol or literal (unclear in your code).

Comment: I tried it (before posting the answer) with the iris dataset and it worked perfectly:

`newcol = "petal_length"`
`oldcol = "Petal.Length"`

`iris %>% rename_with(~newcol, oldcol)`

In this `rename_with` expression, the first argument would be the dataframe (omitted through the pipe), the second one the function and the third one the old varname. This argument also allows you to use literals, because as stated in the documentation: "Should return a character vector the same length as the input."

Comment: I edited your comment code into the question, as it makes it functional and meaningful. Note that the use of `oldcol` in that way is deprecated, it should be `rename_with(~newcol, all_of(oldcol))` (or `any_of`).